# Como resolver redirecionamento indevido de página em form?

Tags: javascript, ajax, wordpress

Estou criando uma land-page para captação de leads. Preciso que passar os arquivos via ajax para não ter que redirecionar a página, contudo sempre que eu envio os dados para a página que deve fazer o include no banco de dados ele tenta redirecionar a página para uma página de curso ou coisa do tipo. Como Ajax não é meu forte, preciso da ajuda de vocês para saber onde está o erro.
Acho importante ressaltar que o site é feito em wordpress.
Como posso resolver este problema?

```js
 $("#submit").submit(function (e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#submit").val('Enviando...');
        $.ajax({
            url: 'process.php',
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'html',
            data: {
                'metodo': $('#metodo').val(),
                'nome': $('#nome').val(),
                'sobrenome': $('#sobrenome').val(),
                'email': $('#email').val(),
                'telefone': $('#telefone').val(),
                'curso': $('#curso').val()    
            }
        }).done(function (data){
            alert(data);
            
            $("#submit").val('Enviar');
            $('#nome').val('');
            $('#sobrenome').val('');
            $('#email').val('');
            $('#telefone').val('');
            $('#curso').val('');
            
        });
    });
```

```html
<form class="cata-lead">
                <div class="lp-titulo">
                    Preencha este formulário e garanta seu futuro entre os <obs>melhores</obs>.
                </div>
                <div class="item-cata-lead">
                    <input type="text" name="nome" id="nome" placeholder="Primeiro Nome*"/>
                    <input type="text" name="sobrenome" id="sobrenome" placeholder="Sobrenome*"/>
                    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="E-mail*"/>
                    <input type="tel" name="telefone" id="telefone" placeholder="Telefone*"/>
                    <select name="curso" id="curso">
                    <!--Laço para preenchimento dos cursos disponíveis-->
                        <option>Curso de interesse*</option>
                        <?php
                            foreach ($cursos as $curso):
                        ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo utf8_encode($curso['nome']); ?>">
                            <?php echo utf8_encode($curso['nome']); ?>
                        </option>
                        <?php
                            endforeach;
                        ?>
                    </select>
                    <input type="hidden" id="metodo" value="metodo">
                    <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submeter" value="Estou interessado!">
                </div>
            </form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Só colocar return false no final da função, e colocar o evento submit no form e não no botão exemplo:

```
$(".cata-lead").submit(function (e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#submit").val('Enviando...');
        $.ajax({
            url: 'process.php',
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'html',
            data: {
                'metodo': $('#metodo').val(),
                'nome': $('#nome').val(),
                'sobrenome': $('#sobrenome').val(),
                'email': $('#email').val(),
                'telefone': $('#telefone').val(),
                'curso': $('#curso').val()    
            }
        }).done(function (data){
            alert(data);

            $("#submit").val('Enviar');
            $('#nome').val('');
            $('#sobrenome').val('');
            $('#email').val('');
            $('#telefone').val('');
            $('#curso').val('');

        });
       return false;
    });
```

Comment: Everaldo, agradeço sua contribuição. De fato resolveu meu problema!

Answer (score 2):

Estás a usar o seletor errado, esse código na verdade nunca chega a correr pois o botão `#submit` não tem nenhum evento `submit`, só a `<form>` é que tem. Ou usas `.click` no botão, ou usas `.submit` na `<form>`.

Portanto:

```
$("#submit").click(function (e){
    e.preventDefault();
```

ou

```
$(".cata-lead").submit(function (e){
    e.preventDefault();
```

Comment: funcionou do jeito que você colocou, mas o Everaldo respondeu primeiro. De toda forma, obrigado pela resposta.